# Iterative Creation Myths: Rare or Just Obscure?

Tags: creation

I noticed that in the categorisation of creation myths, there isn't a slot for iterative creation, i.e. where one world is created after another (with or without destroying the previous one), *without* the expectation of infinite cycles.

An example would be the [Five Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Suns), but aside from it, I seem to have trouble finding more examples. [Even my recent question about the octopus sneaking in from a previous realm seems to be based on an *outsider's interpretation*](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/in-what-myth-the-octopus-hails-from-a-previous-world/5740#5740). There are a few works of recent fiction that explicitly or implicitly rely on iterations of worlds, but of course those aren't *really* mythologies in the usual sense.

**Are iterative world creation myths that uncommon, or am I just looking in the wrong places?** If the former, what's so special about them that makes them so rare? If the latter, what would be other solid examples?